# Implement custom modules for checkstyle

Tags: java, gradle, checkstyle

I've created a plugin which invokes the Checkstyle plugin for all the sub projects in a project. Executing simple checkstyle rules against any of the projects works fine, but when I introduce my custom Module, the build process throws up
`Caused by: com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.CheckstyleException: Unable to instantiate 'com.test.gradle.plugin.perf.MethodLimitCheck' class`

This class has the custom rule, that I want checkstyle to run. My plugin gets triggered during the build of the project and tries to run this custom module where it fails. Tried going through a lot of online resources but couldn't find anything. I'm using Checkstyle version `8.17`.

Why is the other project not able to instantiate the class? Even when the class is a part of the plugin jar, which is attached to the other project ?
What is the correct way to attach a custom module ?

Comment: @barfuin its gradle. My plugin plugs into other gradle projects and runs the Checkstyle plugin, with custom modules for checks. Whenever I add a custom check, the build fails, as the checkstyle class loader is not able to instantiate the custom class that I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

For Gradle, custom checks must be placed on the classpath of the analysis run by adding the custom check to the `checkstyle` configuration. Example from the [Checkstyle Addons](https://checkstyle-addons.thomasjensen.com/run.html#run-gradle) library (basically a collection of custom checks):

```
plugins {
    id 'checkstyle'  // regular Checkstyle plugin
}
dependencies {
    checkstyle group: 'com.thomasjensen.checkstyle.addons', name: 'checkstyle-addons', version: '5.2.2'
}
checkstyle {
    configFile file('your-checkstyle.xml')
    toolVersion '8.0'   // set Checkstyle version here
}
```